How can I add a product preview in the text editor using the free toolbar options?
For a product review site, I have to develop an input form that allows the user to add product previews in his article to suggest to his readers.
I have created test files reproducing the operation of the original project in order to illustrate my requirement as clearly as possible.
This is the input form where TinyMCE is used to write the article/review.
Preview of the insertion form
This, on the other hand, is the source code of the page containing the insertion form.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/langs/it.js"></script>
    <style>
      form {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
      }

      form .row {
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      form .row label {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 0;
      }

      form input[type="submit"] {
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      tinymce.init({

        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: 'table lists link image media codesample fullscreen code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | fontsizeinput forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | numlist bullist | table | link unlink | image media | codesample code fullscreen',
        language: 'it',
        link_default_target: '_blank'

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="actions/save.php">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="titolo">Titolo</label>
          <input type="text" name="titolo" id="titolo">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="testo">Testo</label>
          <textarea name="testo" id="testo"></textarea>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salva">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

Among the options available free of charge in the TinyMCE toolbar I found the source code tool where I can add the product preview using the iframe tag
Source code toolbar option
However, I do not want to display the product preview within an iframe but intend to add it in the text editor with its template (get-product-preview.php)
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/params.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = $dbh->prepare(

  'SELECT prodotto, immagine, prezzo FROM prodotti WHERE id = :id'

);

$sql->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id']);

$sql->execute();

$row = $sql->fetch();

?>
<style>
  .product {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .product h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
  }

  .details {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .details img {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .details .price {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
</style>
<div class="product">
  <h2><?php echo $row['prodotto'] ?></h2>
  <div class="details">
    <img src="prodotti/<?php echo $row['immagine'] ?>">
    <span class="price"><?php echo $row['prezzo'] ?> €</span>
  </div>
</div>

which from the browser is displayed like this
Product preview from browser
To obtain this preview in the text editor
Product Preview in the Text Editor
This is the database table from which I obtain the main information for the product preview
Database table
How can I add the product preview in the TinyMCE text editor without an iframe?

The question is a bit long, but perfectly answerable. You need to insert/nest the output of your get-product-preview.php inside the <textarea> tag. You could use file_get_contents() for this, which might not always work, or keep it simple and include what you need.

I cannot add include and file_get_contents inside tinymce to preview the product immediately. Tinymce comments each PHP instruction.

But you can in your form file: ...... <textarea name="testo" id="testo"><?php  include "get-product-preview.php"; ?></textarea> ....... Make sure that your form file ends in .php, so it runs through the PHP interpreter, and that the get-product-preview.php is in the same directory. Note that the styles you include this way could cause some problems.

I do not need to include the file get-product-preview.php inside the textarea when loading the page. I need to allow the user to add previews of the products he/she will review in the text editor. Using the source code option to add the iframe would solve the problem, in theory. But the product preview template would not be included in the review. Instead, it is absolutely important that the template with the main product information is added.

I had two solutions in mind: 1) Add the iframe when inserting and updating the review, replacing it with the product preview template when the review is displayed publicly; 2) Add a placeholder with the product id to be replaced with the product preview template when the review is displayed publicly. However, I hope that someone has already solved this problem and can show me the quickest way, perhaps using a tinymce option that currently escapes me.
